# socket.recv()の待機時間中に、PyQt5のプログレスバーを進めたい

Tags: python, pyqt, socket

## 実現したいこと

PyQT5を使って簡単なGUIを作っています。
その際、ソケット通信を行いサーバから受け取ったデータをGUI上に表示しようと思っています。

そこで、socketモジュールのsocket.recv()を使ってデータを受けとるようにしましたが、
socket.recv()の待機時間が10秒ほどあり、その間、プログレスバーで時間経過を表示したいです。

## 実装したコード

以下のようにコードを実装してみましたが、
socket.recv()の待機時間中はプログレスバーが止まってしまいます。
具体的な改善点などして頂けると助かります。

```
import socket
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication, QPushButton, QProgressBar, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBasicTimer
import threading

class Example(QWidget)

  def __init__(self):
    self.button = QPushButton("Run!")
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.threading_wrapper)
    self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)         #18/06/22 追記
    self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25) #18/06/22 追記
    self.step = 0                          #18/06/22 追記
    self.timer = QBasicTimer()             #18/06/22 追記

  def threading_wrapper(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.send_socket)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

  def send_socket(self):
    ...
    self.timer.start(100, self)                           # 18/06/22 追記
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # 18/06/22 追記
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))                         # 18/06/22 追記
    s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))                           # 18/06/22 追記
    r = socket.recv()
    self.timer.stop()                                     # 18/06/22 追記
    ...

  def timeEvent(self, e):
    self.step = self.step + 1     # 18/06/22 追記
    self.pbar.setValue(self.step) # 18/06/22 追記
    if self.step > 100:           # 18/06/22 追記
      self.timer.stop()           # 18/06/22 追記
```

Comment: `QBasicTimer`で時間経過を見ていると予想しますが、コード例のどこで`QBasicTimer.start`させていますか? 質問文に追記くださると助かります。

Comment: @user20098
`QBasicTimer`関係のコードを追加しました。
お手すきの時にでも、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QBasicTimer.start`を別スレッド(`threading.Thread`のスレッド)で呼んでいるので、タイマーの起動に失敗しているか(`QApplication`の)イベントディスパッチャで処理されていないためと予想します。
「`self.timer.start(100, self)`」を`threading_wrapper`メソッド側で呼び出すとタイマーが動作し、`Example.timerEvent()`が呼び出されるようになると思います。

---

なお、PyQt(Qt)の機能をスレッドで利用するのであれば、`threading.Thread`ではなく、`QtCore.QThread`でスレッド生成して処理する方が、相性がよいと思います。(`QThread`は
イベントディスパッチャ機能を持っているため)

＃`QThread`を使った修正例は省略しますが、`socket_send`メソッドの内容を`QThread`の拡張クラスの`run()`メソッドとして実装する、等の方法で実現可能です。